# Why do `sbrk`, `mmap` etc. return very long addresses?

Tags: c, operating-system, posix, paging, virtual-memory

When I `mmap` a block of memory, the returned pointer might be something like `2607194112` or `3614339072` (both actual values I've gotten).

Why are these values seemingly so random? It's all virtual anyway, so why not just give me address `4096` to start us off?

I suppose this question extends also to something like `malloc`, but that will use one of these under the hood anyways.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: @erik258 thank you! That's an acceptable answer if it's summarised into a sentence or two. Otherwise, I'll answer my own question. It would be very helpful to note at what level this is implemented -- is it inside of the `mmap` implementation, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @erik258 mentioned, it's because of [Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (ASLR). Without that feature, it would be pretty easier for attackers to predict addresses of your code and libc functions and execute return-to-libc attacks. It implemented under the kernel - so far all this functions get such random values (`malloc`, `mmap`, etc).

Answer (score 3):

You're observing [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

> In order to prevent an attacker from reliably jumping to, for example, a particular exploited function in memory, ASLR randomly arranges the address space positions of key data areas of a process

Answer (score 0):

> Why are these values seemingly so random? It's all virtual anyway, so why not just give me address 4096 to start us off?

without specifying the operating system and architecture of your system, it's not possible to say.  But as somebody has pointed out, the `malloc` library tries to take advantage (and for security reasons too) by acquiring memory segments spread enough in the full 64bit virtual address space of your computer (that is, indeed, huge)  This will allow a malicious process that, for some reason has access to your virtual space, to have almost no probability of guessing where in memory your data is.  But as a side effect, you get all those big numbers.   You don't tell if you are in such a 64bit cpu, but it's common in linux, to have this spread of memory segments to allow for big holes of unused memory in its virtual address space, interspersed with small used segments.  Also, the probability of a stack collision with a memory segment is low (while this is checked anyway by other means) or the grow of a data segment to overlap another segment to be impossible.